# IntelliJ - Angular - How to diagram only the modules?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, diagram

I am using the latest Ultimate Edition of IntelliJ and am attempting to generate a useful diagram for a project I am on that does not have any documentation. I am doing this to make it easy to see what all of the modules are and what modules they interact with.
The problem that I am running into is that everything that is imported is being generated into the diagram making it much larger than needed.
I would like to limit the diagramming to only MODULES and not everything else.

I was able to figure out that I can click all of the Modules I want and then diagram from those to see what they interact with but still am getting too many additional pieces in my diagram.
IntelliJ does not directly address this information in their help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-module-dependencies-diagram.html#view_module_diagram

**Does anyone know how I might get the diagram size reduced by only showing Modules?**

Trying to export sometimes fails because of a memory issue.

Sadly my home system I built 10 years ago has more processing power than this newer machine at work.

> Just a tip to anyone out there. Ways to diagram
>
> - Right Click on a folder and select Diagrams -> Show Diagram... (Not the best option)
> - Select one or more files then Right Click on a folder and select Diagrams -> Show Diagram...

*** ---------------- ***

*** A tool suggested to me from a comment below that does the job! ***

*** [Compodoc](https://compodoc.app/guides/getting-started.html) ***

*** ---------------- ***

> What is [Compodoc](https://compodoc.app/guides/getting-started.html) ?
>
> Compodoc is a documentation tool for Angular applications. It
>   generates a static documentation of your application.

Comment: [compodoc](https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc) might be helpful.

Comment: @lealceldeiro This looks promising. I updated my post with some information about that tool.

Comment: Why is this labelled as Angular? The diagram generator in IntelliJ is for Java only. A tool like compodoc is for Angular, and won't work with Java.

Comment: @Reactgular The tool in IntelliJ does work with Angular. The project I'm on is an Angular project. The diagramming I believe only works for the Angular projects if you have the Ultimate Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to do this in IDEA. Please vote for [WEB-35691](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35691) and linked tickets to be notified on any progress with them